# High Precision Metallic Means

Tags: code-golf

### Background

The [metallic means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metallic_mean), starting with the famous [golden mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio), are defined for every natural number (positive integer), and each one is an irrational constant (it has an infinite non-recurring decimal expansion).

For a natural number [image], the [image] metallic mean is the root of a quadratic equation [image]

The roots are always

[image]

but the metallic mean is usually given as the positive root. So for this question it will be defined by:

[image]

For [image] the result is the famous golden ratio:

[image]

---

### Challenge

Your code should take 2 inputs: n and p *(the order is not important as long as it is consistent)*

- n is a natural number indicating which metallic mean
- p is a natural number indicating how many decimal places of precision

Your code should output the nth metallic mean to p decimal places precision.

#### Validity

Your code is valid if it works for values of n and p from 1 to 65,535.

You must output a decimal in the form

digit(s).digit(s) (without spaces)

For example, the golden mean to 9 decimal places is

1.618033988

Display the last digit without rounding, as it would appear in a longer decimal expansion. The next digit in the golden mean is a 7, but the final 8 in the example should not be rounded up to a 9.

The number of decimal digits must be p, which means any trailing zeroes must also be included.

Answers of the form

[image]

are not valid - you must use a decimal expansion.

You may output up to 1 leading newline and up to 1 trailing newline. You may not output any spaces, or any other characters besides digits and the single point/full stop/period.

### Score

This is standard code golf: your score is the number of bytes in your code.

---

## Leaderboard

*(Using [Martin's leaderboard snippet](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/leaderboard-snippet))*

```js
var QUESTION_ID=52493;function answersUrl(e){return"http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),e.has_more?getAnswers():process()}})}function shouldHaveHeading(e){var a=!1,r=e.body_markdown.split("\n");try{a|=/^#/.test(e.body_markdown),a|=["-","="].indexOf(r[1][0])>-1,a&=LANGUAGE_REG.test(e.body_markdown)}catch(n){}return a}function shouldHaveScore(e){var a=!1;try{a|=SIZE_REG.test(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0])}catch(r){}return a}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){answers=answers.filter(shouldHaveScore).filter(shouldHaveHeading),answers.sort(function(e,a){var r=+(e.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[1/0])[0],n=+(a.body_markdown.split("\n")[0].match(SIZE_REG)||[1/0])[0];return r-n});var e={},a=1,r=null,n=1;answers.forEach(function(s){var t=s.body_markdown.split("\n")[0],o=jQuery("#answer-template").html(),l=(t.match(NUMBER_REG)[0],(t.match(SIZE_REG)||[0])[0]),c=t.match(LANGUAGE_REG)[1],i=getAuthorName(s);l!=r&&(n=a),r=l,++a,o=o.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",i).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",c).replace("{{SIZE}}",l).replace("{{LINK}}",s.share_link),o=jQuery(o),jQuery("#answers").append(o),e[c]=e[c]||{lang:c,user:i,size:l,link:s.share_link}});var s=[];for(var t in e)e.hasOwnProperty(t)&&s.push(e[t]);s.sort(function(e,a){return e.lang>a.lang?1:e.lang<a.lang?-1:0});for(var o=0;o<s.length;++o){var l=jQuery("#language-template").html(),t=s[o];l=l.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",t.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",t.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",t.size).replace("{{LINK}}",t.link),l=jQuery(l),jQuery("#languages").append(l)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",answers=[],page=1;getAnswers();var SIZE_REG=/\d+(?=[^\d&]*(?:&lt;(?:s&gt;[^&]*&lt;\/s&gt;|[^&]+&gt;)[^\d&]*)*$)/,NUMBER_REG=/\d+/,LANGUAGE_REG=/^#*\s*([^,]+)/;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"><div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table></div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table></div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## dc, 12

```
?kdd*4+v+2/p
```

- `?` Push n and p onto the stack
- `k` set precision to p
- `dd` duplicate n twice (total three copies)
- `*` multiply n*n
- `4+` add 4
- `v` take square root
- `+` add n (last copy on stack)
- `2/` divide by 2
- `p` print

#### Testcase:

```
$ dc -f metalmean.dc <<< "1 9"
1.618033988
$
```

Comment: Right tool for the job.

Comment: @Dennis its got to be the first time CJam is nearly 3 times as long as something else ;-)

Answer (score 2):

## R, 116 bytes

```r
library(Rmpfr);s=scan();n=mpfr(s[1],1e6);r=(n+(4+n^2)^.5)/2;t=toString(format(r,s[2]+2));cat(substr(t,1,nchar(t)-1))
```

This reads two integers from STDIN and prints the result to STDOUT. You can [try it online](http://www.r-fiddle.org/#/fiddle?id=nDZLCRyq).

Ungolfed + explanation:

```r
# Import the Rmpfr library for arbitrary precision floating point arithmetic
library(Rmpfr)

# Read two integers from STDIN
s <- scan()

# Set n equal to the first input as an mpfr object with 1e6 bits of precision
n <- mpfr(s[1], 1e6)

# Compute the result using the basic formula
r <- (n + sqrt(4 + n^2)) / 2

# Get the rounded string representation of r with 1 more digit than necessary
t <- toString(format(r, s[2] + 2))

# Print the result with p unrounded digits
cat(substr(t, 1, nchar(t) - 1))
```

If you don't have the `Rmpfr` library installed, you can `install.packages("Rmpfr")` and all of your dreams will come true.

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 50 bytes

```
SetAccuracy[Floor[(#+Sqrt[4+#^2])/2,10^-#2],#2+1]&
```

Defines an anonymous function that takes `n` and `p` in order.  I use `Floor` to prevent rounding with `SetAccuracy`, which I need in order to get decimal output.

Comment: @Arcinde I can't use machine precision numbers unfortunately, since they wouldn't be able to handle `p>15`.

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, 35 bytes

```
1'el+~1$*_2#2$2#4*+mQ+2/1$md@+s0'.t
```

Reads **p** first, then **n**.

Try it online in the [CJam interpreter](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=1'el%2B~1%24*_2%232%242%234*%2BmQ%2B2%2F1%24md%40%2Bs0'.t&input=19%201).

#### How it works

We simply compute the formula from the question for **n × 10<sup>p</sup>**, get the integer and fractional part of the result divided by **10<sup>p</sup>**, pad the fractional part with leading zeroes to obtain **p** digits and print the parts separated by a dot.

```
1'e  e# Push 1 and 'e'.
l+   e# Read a line from STDIN and prepend the 'e'.
~    e# Evaluate. This pushes 10**p (e.g., 1e3 -> 1000) and n.
1$*  e# Copy 10**p and multiply it with n.
_2#  e# Copy n * 10**p and square it.
2$   e# Copy 10**p.
2#4* e# Square and multiply by 4.
+    e# Add (n * 10**p)**2 and 4 * 10**2p.
mQ   e# Push the integer part of the square root.
+2/  e# Add to n * 10**p and divide by 2.
1$md e# Perform modular division by 10**p.
@+s  e# Add 10**p to the fractional part and convert to string. 
0'.t e# Replace the first character ('1') by a dot.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python 2, 92 Bytes

As I am now looking at the answers, it looks like the CJam answer uses the same basic method as this. It calculates the answer for `n*10**p` and then adds in the decimal point. It is incredibly inefficient due to the way it calculates the integer part of the square root (just adding 1 until it gets there).

```py
n,p=input()
e=10**p;r=0
while(n*n+4)*e*e>r*r:r+=1
s=str((n*e+r-1)/2);print s[:-p]+'.'+s[-p:]
```

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <strike>85</strike> 78 bytes

```
echo bcdiv(bcadd($n=$argv[bcscale($argv[2])],bcsqrt(bcadd(4,bcpow($n,2)))),2);
```

It uses the [BC Math](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) mathematical extension which, on some systems, could not be available. It needs to be included on the [compilation time](http://php.net/manual/en/bc.installation.php) by specifying the `--enable-bcmath` command line option. It is always available on Windows and it seems it is included in the PHP version bundled with OSX too.

**Update**:

I applied all the hacks suggested by @blackhole in their comments (thank you!) then I squeezed the initialization of `$n` into its first use (3 more bytes saved) and now the code fits in a single line in the code box above.

Comment: @Blackhole. 85, indeed. I have probably read 86 (did a slightly larger selection) and wrote 68 by mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: No problem :). You can have 1 byte less by the way: remove the parenthesis around the `echo`, just leave a space after it.

Comment: And since you expect `bcscale` to return `true`, you can use `$n=$argv[bcscale($argv[2])];` and save 2 more bytes.

Comment: That's a nice hack.

Comment: Code dirtiness is an art :P. Oh, the last one: [`bcpow($n,2)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcpow.php) instead of `bcmul($n,$n)` saves you 1 byte.

Answer (score 1):

## J, 27 Bytes

```
4 :'}:":!.(2+x)-:y+%:4+*:y'
```

#### Explanation:

```
4 :'                      '   | Define an explicit dyad
                       *:y    | Square y
                     4+       | Add 4
                   %:         | Square root
                 y+           | Add y
               -:             | Half
      ":!.(2+x)               | Set print precision to 2+x
    }:                        | Remove last digit, to fix rounding
```

Call it like this:

```
    9 (4 :'}:":!.(2+x)-:y+%:4+*:y') 1
1.618033988
```

Another, slightly cooler solution:

```
4 :'}:":!.(2+x){.>{:p._1,1,~-y'
```

Which calculates the roots of the polynomial x^2 - nx - 1. Unfortunately, the way J formats the result makes retreving the desired root slightly longer.